# boost regex not matching?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to follow the example here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html

I want to match lines of this form:

```
[ foo77 ]
```

which should be simple enough, I tried a code snippet like this:

```
boost::regex rx("^\[ (.+) \]");

boost::cmatch what;
if (boost::regex_match(line.c_str(), what, rx)) std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

but I am not matching those lines. I tried the following variant expressions:

```
"^\[[:space:]+(.+)[:space:]+\]$" //matches nothing
"^\[[:space:]+(.+)[:space:]+\]$" //matches other lines but not the ones I want.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fast guess:  You might have to escape the '\'. In your case:  boost::regex rx("^\\\[ (.+) \\\]");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `boost::regex rx("^\[ (.+) \]");` to `boost::regex rx("^\\[ (.+) \\]");`, it will work fine, the compiler should warn about the unrecognized character escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` within the regular expression, otherwise your compiler will consider `"\["` as an (invalid) escape sequence.

```
boost::regex rx("^\\[ (.+) \\]");
```

A better solution is to use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

```
boost::regex rx(R"(^\[ (.+) \])");
```

Comment: Raw string literals are only available in C++11.  And if he had C++11, he'd be using `std::regex` instead of Boost (presumably, at least).

Comment: @James Unless he's using gcc, `std::regex` doesn't really work in versions prior to 4.9.